# How to create a Flow.Publisher that starts on subscribe from an akka-stream Source

Tags: java, akka, akka-stream

I have a java interface that I have to implement that looks like that:

```
public Flow.Publisher<Packet> getLivePublisher();
```

This interface must return a `Flow.Publisher` that stays inactive until it is subscribed to, and the subscriber calls `Subscription.next(n)`.

So far, my implementation looks like

```
return Source
    .fromIterator(() -> new LivePacketIterator())
    .async("live-dispatcher")
    .runWith(JavaFlowSupport.Sink.asPublisher(AsPublisher.WITHOUT_FANOUT), actorSystem);
```

Unfortunately, this seems to immediately start getting elements from my `LivePacketIterator`, even when no subscribers ahve subscribed to the returned `Flow.Publisher`.

I understand that a `Source` is just a sort of a template for a Subscribable source of objects (my understanding is that it's like a Factory of Publishers), and that it only converts to a concrete active source once it's materialized. So if I understand correctly, I need to somehow materialize my `Source` to get a `Flow.Publisher`. But I want it to be materialized in a way that it only starts running when it is subscribed to.

I've also tried to use `toMat()`

```
return Source
                .fromIterator(() -> new LivePacketIterator(maximumPacketSize))
                .filter(OrderSnapshotPacket::isNotEmpty)
                .async(dbDispatcher)
                .toMat(JavaFlowSupport.Sink.asPublisher(AsPublisher.WITHOUT_FANOUT), Keep.right())
                .???;
```

But I'm not sure what to do with the resulting `RunnableGraph`.

Am I understanding this correctly?
Is there a way to do what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Unfortunately, this seems to immediately start getting elements from my LivePacketIterator, even when no subscribers ahve subscribed to the returned Flow.Publisher.

What exactly do you observe to state this? I used a very similar snippet to yours:

```
Flow.Publisher<Integer> integerPublisher =
      Source.from(List.of(1,2,3,4,5))
            .wireTap(System.out::println)
            .async()
            .runWith(
              JavaFlowSupport.Sink.asPublisher(AsPublisher.WITHOUT_FANOUT),
              ActorSystem.create());
```

This will not start emitting items from the list until the publisher is subscribed to.

> I understand that a Source is just a sort of a template for a Subscribable source of objects (my understanding is that it's like a Factory of Publishers), and that it only converts to a concrete active source once it's materialized

Kind of. All `Flow.*` interfaces are part of [reactive streams specification](https://github.com/reactive-streams/reactive-streams-jvm/blob/v1.0.3/README.md) for JVM. Akka Streams treats those interfaces as SPI and doesn't use them directly in its API. It introduces its own abstractions like `Source`, `Flow` and `Sink`. Akka Streams allows you to convert the processing stream expressed in its API to the lower level Flow.* just as you did in your snippet. This is useful if you say want to plugin Akka Streams processing pipeline to some other reactive streams implementation like say [RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava) or [Project Reactor](https://projectreactor.io/). So `Source` is Akka Stream's abstraction that is somehow equivalent to `Flow.Publisher`, that is, it's a source of potentially infinite number of values. You need to connect `Source` to a `Sink` (potentially via a `Flow`) so that you get a `RunnableGraph` which you can *run*. This will set everything in motion and in *most cases* it will cause chain of subscriptions and elements will start flowing through the stream. But that is not the only option in case of `JavaFlowSupport.Sink.asPublisher` `Sink`, running the `RunnableGraph` will convert the whole Akka Stream to an instance of `Flow.Publisher`. The semantics here is that the subscription is deferred until something somewhere calls `subscribe` on that instance. Which is exactly what you're trying to achieve if I understand correctly.

Comment: I think I found the source of my problem. I was atcually using `Source.concat()` which appears to early pull the first element of both concatenated sources. A fact that the extremely obtuse documentation is really good at obfuscating. In the end, I solved my problem by using Source.concatLazy() instead.

Comment: Makes sense, you just skipped that `Source.concat` part in your question :)

Comment: I know, I didn't think it was relevant, but turns out it was. I'm going to accept your answer anyway as it's probably the best answer that can be given due to my malformed question :-)